# What seems to be wrong in my C++ calculator?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int num1,num2,answer;
char choice = 'Y',input;

while (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y')
{
    cout << "Enter the first number: " << endl;
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter the second number: " << endl;
    cin >> num2;

    cout << "What operation would you like to use?" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Press [A] if you want to use Addition." << endl;
    cout << "Press [S] if you want to use Subtraction." << endl;
    cout << "Press [M] if you want to use Multiplication." << endl;
    cout << "Press [D] if you want to use Division." << endl;

    switch(input)
    {
        case 'A':
        case 'a':
            {
                answer=num1+num2;
                cout << "This is the sum of your equation: " << answer << endl;
                break;
            }
        case 'S':
        case 's':
            {
                answer=num1-num2;
                cout << "This is the difference of your equation: " << answer << endl;
                break;
            }
        case 'M':
        case 'm':
            {
                answer=num1*num2;
                cout << "This is the product of your equation: " << answer << endl;
                break;
            }
        case 'D':
        case 'd':
            {
                answer=num1/num2;
                cout << "This is the quotient of your equation: " << answer << endl;
                break;
            }
        default:
            {
                cout << "Invalid Operation..." << endl;
                break;
            }
    }
    cout << "Do you want to go again? (Y/N) " << endl;
    cin >> choice;
}

cout << "See you later." << endl;

return 0;
}
```

So I just started college about a month and a half ago, and I thought that I'd try out the codes that still hasn't been taught to us. But I ran into a problem, whenever I build my program it shows no error. But it does not do what I had intended it to do, to be a calculator. It immediately jumps to, "Do you want to go again?" After inputting the 2 numbers and it won't let the user even choose an operation let alone calculate it. What seems to be wrong with my code?

[EDIT]
I forgot to put cin >> input; right after asking for which operation to use.

Comment: do you ever assign anything to `input` ?

Comment: Always pay attention to your compiler's warnings. There should be something among the lines of "uninitialized local variable 'input' used".

Comment: You ask for what operation they want to use, but you never use `cin` to get that response.  You need to use `cin` to put a value into `input`.

Comment: 1) "_whenever I build my program it shows no error. But it does not do what I had intended it to do_" If the code compiles - it means that it is syntactically correct, not that it will run without issues. Compiler, can't (yet) read your mind, so it compiles the code you wrote, not the code, that you intended to write. 2) Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Don't put `[ANSWERED]` - in the title: it's useless fluff. Once you accept an answer, it's quote obvious, that the question is answered, without opening it. Nor edit your question with the answer. If the answer was posted in the comments: write the answer, and accept it, yourself

Comment: Oh alright, thanks for the info

Comment: @MeltingPaint_ "_Oh alright, thanks for the info_" Such information shouldn't have come from me, though. It should have been present in the [tour], and/or in the [help], that you should've read, before asking the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggest, you need to get a value for your `input` variable at some point. I would suggest immediately before the `switch` that depends on it:

```
    cin >> input; // You forgot to put this line in, I think!
    switch(input)
    {
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you increase the warning level on your compiler, for example using `-Wall` for GCC, you get a useful warning explaining your problem:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':

<source>:8:19: warning: 'input' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]

    8 | char choice = 'Y',input;

      |                   ^~~~~

Compiler returned: 0
```

Comment: It's a shame there's no GCC warning that says: ***will be used*** uninitialized!